# Kendo MVC ComboBox with million records - Initial Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo ComboBox as an EditorTemplate for nullable IDs (people). I bind the model normally with a UIHint

```
 @Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x=>x.Person.MotherID)
```

The combo works great, I can type and it filters on the server.

The problem is that when the form first loads, the **ID** of the person appears as the visible text, not the **name**.

There are **1 million records**, so I can't send them all to the combobox initially.

How do I get the combobox, **when it first renders**, to go get the name of the person via Ajax and not show the ID?

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .ComboBoxFor(m => m)
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .AutoBind(true)
      .ValuePrimitive(true)
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
      .Placeholder(Words.Type_Name)
      .MinLength(2)
      .DataSource(source =>
          source.Read(read =>
                      read.Action("ReadComboBoxPerson", "Picker", new { area = "" }))
              .ServerFiltering(true))
      )
```

MVC:

```
public ActionResult ReadComboBoxPerson(string text)
    {
        return Json(_personManager.PersonGetter(text), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Not very familiar with Kendo ComboBox, but can you set the `.text` property to display the initial value? something like `.text(Model.Name)`

Comment: Any answers found on this one? I do have the same problem